# EasyUI - XML data load into datagrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, xml-parsing, jquery-easyui

folks,

This is in continuation of question posted at http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=1144 .

I'm trying to load an XML data (though by default easyui consume json). The example in the forum shows how to load xml if its written as it is, but not a way to link a xml file or URL.

Essentially, the question is

**How to load XML File into an easyUI datagrid**

Currently "data" is specified as

```
data: '<root><people><name>name1</name><address>address1</address></people><people><name>name2</name><address>address2</address></people></root>',
```

But is it possible to have data as a file or URL

```
data: '/some/url/input.xml'
```

Full sample below.

```
<table class="easyui-datagrid" title="Load XML Data" style="width:300px;height:200px"       
            data-options="  
            **data: '/some/url/input.xml',**            
            loadFilter: function(xml){
                    var rows = [];
                    $(xml).find('people').each(function(){
                        var p = $(this);
                        var row = {
                            name: p.find('name').text(),
                            address: p.find('address').text()
                        };
                        rows.push(row);
                    });
                    return {total:rows.length,rows:rows};   
                }       
    ">  
    <thead>         
        <tr>            
            <th data-options="field:'name'">Name</th>           
            <th data-options="field:'address'">Address</th>         
        </tr>   
    </thead> 
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't find in easyui. But I wrote a xml->json parser in the backend

Comment: Did that solve your answer?  It is working great for me.  Little too late for you, I guess, but it might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this.  It takes a bit of work and some moving data back and forth from one format to another.  I started with the CRUD datagrid tutorial version so my answer might be a bit different.  I started from the CRUD example, converting from the mySQL solution to instead use XML.
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud2.php

```
$(function(){
        $('#dg').edatagrid({
            url: 'get_data.php' /* pulls in the data from a xml file  */
        });
    });
```

My example actually had the read (url), create (saveURL), update (updateURL), and delete (destroyUrl) but for this answer I just put the url to read the data in.

For my get_data.php I converted my XML file into JSON.  I also removed a root I had in that XML file.

```
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file("mydata.xml", null, LIBXML_NOCDATA)) {
echo "unable to load file";
}
{
$xmlarray = array();  // create a new array 
    foreach ($xml as $element) {  // loop through the xml file elements
        array_push($xmlarray, $element);  // push the elements on the xml array
    }
}

echo json_encode($xmlarray);  // encode that json without the root xml element
```

I am still sticking with simplexml, but there are easier ways to do this when you get into removing and updating.  You can use the DOM or another means.